# How to send JSON as response in tokio & warp?

Tags: rust

I want to post the string into the server and deserialize it and send back JSON object via warp. It works fine with strings but it wont send JSON messages to WebSocket client

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Event {
    topic: String,
    user_id: Option<usize>,
    message: String,
    password: String,
}

pub async fn publish_handler(body: Event, clients: Clients) -> Result<impl Reply> {
    if body.password != "password" {
        Ok(StatusCode::from_u16(403).unwrap())
    } else {
        clients
            .read()
            .await
            .iter()
            .filter(|(_, client)| match body.user_id {
                Some(v) => client.user_id == v,
                None => true,
            })
            .filter(|(_, client)| client.topics.contains(&body.topic))
            .for_each(|(_, client)| {
                if let Some(sender) = &client.sender {
                    let json_response: Value = serde_json::from_str(&body.message.clone()).unwrap();
                    let _ = sender.send(Ok(Message::text(json_response)));
                }
            });

        Ok(StatusCode::OK)
    }
}
```

### Error

I get below error:

```
the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<serde_json::Value>` is not satisfied
```

### Dependencies

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.6.0", features = ["full"] }
tokio-stream = "0.1.6"
warp = "0.3.1"
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
futures = { version = "0.3", default-features = false }
uuid = { version = "0.8.2", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, where does the error occur, why do you need to `clone` the string, why is `Event::message` not a `Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message `` the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<serde_json::Value>` is not satisfied ``
comes from these lines:

```rust
let json_response: serde_json::Value;
Message::text(json_response)
```

where `text()` needs a parameter that implements into string:

```rust
fn text<S: Into<String>>(s: S) -> Message {}
```

`serde_json::Value` does not implement `Into<String>` according to the [docs](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) (even though it does implement `to_string()`).

probably all you need then is:

```
Message::text(json_response.to_string()) 
// or if body.message is a string of some type already then
Message::text(&body.message.clone())
```

Also, rust tends to avoid hidden, unexpected, non-explicit heap allocations by default, and `Into<String>` would probably require one.